# Generalizing ATT to the time-varying setting

Tags: causality, treatment-effect, time-varying-covariate

In the case of a point treatment, the average treatment effect among the treated (ATT) is the treatment effect standardized to the subset of the sample that received treatment $A=1$ as an estimate of the treatment effect among patients who would receive treatment in the population. In the potential outcomes formulation, $\mathbb{E}[Y^{a=1}|A=1] - \mathbb{E}[Y^{a=0}|A=1]$ on the risk difference scale.

Can the this estimand be extended to the time-varying case, where we may be interested in the effect of perfect adherence to a treatment regimen $f_a$ in the subset of patients who completely adhered? Analogously, if the inverse probability weights to estimate the ATT for a point treatment are $\frac{P(A=1|\boldsymbol{X})}{1-P(A=1|\boldsymbol{X})}$ for baseline confounders $\boldsymbol{X}$, what would these be for a time-varying ATT?